# How to enable a button based on a TextBox in GridView in ASP.Net using JavaScript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview, user-controls

I have a TextBox in the TemplateField of a GridView. And I have one button below the GridView. I want to enable the Button when I enter some text in the TextBox in the GridView. How to do this? I am using ASP.Net and C#.Net.

My Source Code of the GridView:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>
<asp:GridView ID="gvQCAttribute" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                        CellPadding="0" CssClass="datagrid" DataKeyNames="ItemID" EnableTheming="false"
                        PageSize="10" Width="100%">
                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            QC Attribute Name
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            PO Attribute Value
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            Negative Tolerance
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            Positive Tolerance
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            Remarks
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="rowselect" />
                        <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="table_oddrow" />
                        <RowStyle CssClass="table_evenrow" />
                        <PagerStyle CssClass="pager_style" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ItemID" Visible="false">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblgvItemID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ItemID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QCAttributeID" Visible="false">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblgvQCAttributeID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QCAttributeID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Attribute Name">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="txtQCAttributeName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AttributeName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
                                <ControlStyle Width="100%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="POAttrubute Value">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPOAttributeValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("POAttributeValue") %>'
                                        onkeyup="return EnableButton(this);" ValidationGroup="Modal" onkeypress="return checkNum(event);"></asp:TextBox>

                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                                <ControlStyle Width="95%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Negative Tolerance">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNegTolerance" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NegativeTolerance") %>'
                                        onkeyup="return EnableButton(this);" ValidationGroup="Modal" onkeypress="return checkNum(event);"></asp:TextBox>

                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                                <ControlStyle Width="95%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Positive Tolerance">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPosTolerance" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PositiveTolerance") %>'
                                        onkeyup="return EnableButton(this);" ValidationGroup="Modal" onkeypress="return checkNum(event);"></asp:TextBox>

                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                                <ControlStyle Width="95%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remarks">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRemarks" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Remarks") %>' onkeyup="return EnableButton(this);"
                                        ValidationGroup="Modal"></asp:TextBox>                                        
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                                <ControlStyle Width="95%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
         <asp:Button ID="btnmdeSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="ButtonClass" ValidationGroup="Modal"
                        OnClick="btnmdeSave_Click" />
        </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `onkeypress` or `onkeyup` event and check whether the textbox is empty.

if not, then make the button enable else disable.

```
function enableButton(){
  if(document.getElementById('txtPOAttributeValue').value != '' && document.getElementById('txtNegTolerance').value != '' && document.getElementById('txtPosTolerance').value != ''){
    document.getElementById('buttonId').disabled = false;
  }else{
    document.getElementById('buttonId').disabled = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: hi. it is working for single textbox in a gridview. But I want to enable the button when all the three textbox in a gridview has text.

Comment: @thevan - well, this is your asp code. go to web page on browser and `view page source`, get the raw `html` from there, I can answer you looking that.

Comment: I am placing the GridView and button in Ajax ModalPopupExtender. I couldnt find exactly the code in Source page.

Comment: @thevan - which browser are you using? chrome?

Comment: @thevan - studying your code. I have modified the answer. It should help.

Comment: Hi, I tried but it throws "txtPOAttributeValue does not exist in the Current Context".

Comment: @thevan - may be javascript wont be allowing you to check multiple occurences in `if`, try placing `alert(document.getElementById('txtPOAttributeValue').value)` in function does it show value?

Comment: @thevan - also chk modified answer

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery

```
// disabling button
$("#buttonID").attr('disabled','disabled');

$("#textBoxID").keypress(function(){
   // enabling button
   $("#buttonID").removeAttr('disabled');
});
```